# To display distinct record from datatable on the basis of particular columns but result should be include all columns

Tags: c#, datatable, dataview

i want to get distinct rows from dt on the basis of particulars columns  but result should be displayed with all columns.

Here is code this returning all distinct rows but not binding "Quantity" column of default table:

```
     public static DataTable GetDistinctRecords(DataTable dt)
    {
        DataView view = new DataView(dt);
        DataTable distinctValues = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "ContainerCode", "ProductSKU", "CompanyId", "YearId", "MonthId");

        return distinctValues;
    }
```

My datatable dt has "ContainerCode", "ProductSKU", "CompanyId", "YearId", "MonthId","Quantity" this columns,i want distict record except using Quatity but my new datatable should display this quantity column.

Comment: I think you want Quantity column to be there, but records don't have values of it, right ?